# Substracting row-values from two different text files

Tags: bash

I have two text files, and each file has one column with several rows:
FILE1
  a
  b
  c

FILE2
  d
  e
  f

I want to create a file that has the following output:
a - d
b - e
c - f

All the entries are meant to be numbers (decimals). I am completely stuck and do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You want the actual arithmetic or a string?

Answer (score 2):

Using `paste` seems like the obvious choice but unfortunately you can't specify a multiple character delimiter. To get around this, you can pipe the output to `sed`:

```
$ paste -d- file1 file2 | sed 's/-/ - /'
a - d
b - e
c - f
```

Paste joins the two files together and sed adds the spaces around the `-`.

If your desired output is the result of the subtraction, then you could use awk:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{ print $1 - $2 }'
```

Comment: Based on the title, I think the OP wants the value of `a - d` et al., not just the expressions.

Comment: (which you could do by piping the output to `xargs -n 3 expr`).

Comment: @chepner yeah, looks like you're probably right there. Nice usage of `xargs`!

Answer (score 1):

given:

```
$ cat /tmp/a.txt
1
2
3
$ cat /tmp/b.txt
4
5
6
```

awk is a good bet to process the two files and do arithmetic:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { a[FNR""] = $0; next } { print a[FN""]+$1 }' /tmp/a.txt /tmp/b.txt
5
7
9
```

Or, if you want the strings rather than arithmetic:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { a[FNR""] = $0; next } { print a[FNR""] " - "$0 }' /tmp/a.txt /tmp/b.txt
1 - 4
2 - 5
3 - 6
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution using while and file descriptors :**

```
while read -r line1 <&3  && read -r line2 <&4 
do 
#printf '%s - %s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
printf '%s\n' $(($line1 - $line2))
done 3<f1.txt 4<f2.txt
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the actual subtraction (which is as simple as `printf '%s\n' $(($line1 - $line2))`).